# What and when to use 「きたー」?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

My friend which are Japanese always says きたー when he did something finished, then I asked him the meaning behind it. He said that it was similar よっす！ that kind of expression that you already did something clearly. But again, even my friend are Japanese, and can speak english, sometimes I doubt with his explanation because he always explain it on his own english version (which I found there are many mistaken here and there for word-choice). So what is the actual mean of that word?

Comment: Did he really say よっす? Wasn't it よし or よーし?

Comment: @naruto I don't know the proper one to say よす but something like that

Comment: i tried to translate よーし with google and it says "good day" . it should be "yosh!" right?

Comment: `short for できた` 「できたー」を「きたー」に（意図的に）省略したりしますかね・・・「できたー」の「で」がたまたま聞こえなかったとかならわかりますけど・・

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ ネットスラングの「ｷﾀ━━━━(ﾟ∀ﾟ)━━━━!!」的な意味合いで言っている…ということも考えられるんじゃないですかね

Comment: @GreekFellows そうそう、私はむしろそっちじゃないかなって思ったんです。「来た」→「きたー！」って。ネットスラングだったんですね。日常で‌​使う人が結構いるんで、ただの「はやり言葉」かな​と思ってました。ところでなんかめっちゃお久しぶりですね！

Comment: @Chocolate 「ｷﾀ━」だったとしても、やっぱり使い方がおかしいかなとは思います。何が「来てる」かが分からないので。お久しぶりです！覚えて頂けるとは光栄です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

きたー　would mostly be used, as far as i know, would be either when something is finished being made or something you ordered has arrived. For example you ordered a pizza delivery with your friend, when it arrives you could say "きた、きた！"　or its here, its here!, "きたぞう！"　which is more along the lines of "it has arrived", or if you're a pretty calm person who doesn't have that much of a reaction to things, just "きた。" would work as well. Hoped that helped!

Comment: 返信遅くになりまして、申し訳ございません。この回答が検討あせます。ありがとうございました。